# Grunt template task

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

In my index.html file, I would like to include a different javascript source file in production than I use in development.  I am using requirejs in development and would like to use the single minified file in production.

The project

https://github.com/CaryLandholt/AngularFun

 
does exactly what I would like.

In my project, I am trying to get grunt to run the template task but I am running into problems with it knowing how to complete the task: "Task 'template' not found".

**I don't see anything obvious in the AngularFun project's dependencies that would allow grunt to correctly process the template task, but the project builds correctly.  What am I missing?**

I am asking here because I have seen several questions dealing with different files in prod/dev and the AngularFun project looks like a nice way to do it.

I have a Gruntfile with the following in the initConfig:

```
template: {
  dev: {
    files: {
      "index.html": "index.template"
    },
    environment: "dev"
  },
  prod: {
    files: "<% template.dev.files %>",
    environment: "prod"
  }
}
```

I also have the following as my grunt default:

```
grunt.registerTask("default", ["template:dev"]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template task is located in [grunt-hustler](https://github.com/CaryLandholt/grunt-hustler), an npm package, which must be listed as a dependency in the [package.json](https://github.com/CaryLandholt/AngularFun/blob/master/package.json) file in order for `npm install` to locate it and make it available for your project.

My documentation for grunt-hustler is seriously lacking.

Comment: Thanks!  Sorry, I thought that was probably for the server stuff and overlooked it.  Also, thanks for sharing your project!  It was extremely helpful for learning about requirejs and grunt.